# Выборка данных с LINQ 2 таблиц на основе значений

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq, entity-framework-core

У меня 3 таблицы, посты и кто эти посты выложил(человек или группа):

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    //some code
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public long? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // some code
    public List<Post> Posts {get;set;}
    public User()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string NameGroup { get; set; }
    // some code
    public List<Post> Posts {get;set;}
    public User()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}
```

Условно есть такие списки:

```
List<long> UserIds = { 645, 2456, 9673456, 635 };
List<long> GroupIds = { 3275, 7904, 234 };
```

Как мне на основе таких списков сделать выборку в единый список постов с помощью методов расширения (LINQ). А то в голову приходит только такая реализация:

```
List<Post> Posts = await db.Posts
.Include(d=>d.Group)
.Include(e=>e.User)
.Where(r=>UserIds.Contains(r.UserId)&& GroupIds.Contains(r.GroupId))
.AsNoTracking()
.OrderBy(d => d.DatePost)
.ToListAsync();
```

но она это не работает(

Comment: `.Where(r=>UserIds.Contains(r.UserId)&& GroupIds.Contains(r.GroupId))` замените И на ИЛИ

Comment: У вас EF/EFCore?

Comment: @АндрейNOP EF Core, спасибо заработало

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я так понимаю у меня проблема была в том, что постов от юзеров могло не быть и поэтому выборка возвращала пустой список?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас логическая ошибка в запросе, вы подразумеваете ИЛИ, а пишете И здесь:

```
Where(r => UserIds.Contains(r.UserId) && GroupIds.Contains(r.GroupId))
```

Логическое И возвращает True только в том случае, когда оба операнда истинны, в вашем конкретном случае это в принципе невозможно, т. к. если пост имеет `UserId`, то у него `GroupId == null`, поэтому второй операнд заведомо ложен. И наоборот.

Comment: всё я понял, спасибо большое)